# Differing Flow Cytometry Genome Sizes and Sexual Mating Implies Differing Chromosome Counts

Tags: chromosome, polyploidy, flow-cytometry

**Do the fundamental principles of genetics strongly suggest the following is a derived conjecture?**

***If 2 flowering plant species A and B have widely differing genome size (at a minimum a 50% difference) based on flow cytometry and normal successful sexual mating of A and B is indicated based on the flow cytometry measured genome sizes of the embryo and endosperm of the seeds produced by crossing A and B, then A and B differ in number of chromosomes to a degree indicative of ploidy level differences.***

Corn, Cotton, and Rice are three genus where large genome size differences do not mean differences in chromosome counts.

The Vireya in the genus Rhododendron are a group that have large genome size differences between species where multi-generational hybrids between such species appears to be possible at least in some cases. Documentation suggests that all Vireya have the same chromosome counts indicating diploids.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. Clearly there are examples in _D. melanogaster_, _C. elegans_, and _Z. mays_ where an autosome contains a relatively large contiguous block that is a tandem duplication. This type of genetic rearrangement would have to increase the length of the autosome. As long as the breakpoint does not inactivate an essential gene, and as long as the increased copy number of the affected genes is not lethal, the heterozygotes and homozygotes would be able to reproduce with the wild type.

Comment: I will investigate these 3 examples. I did not realize that autosomes can be widely unequal and normal sexual mating is still possible if the difference in length of the autosomes is due to tandem duplications.